# Crystal reports - read from a table and perform calculations

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Oracle - I'm looking for a way to sum records for over multiple rows and multiple tables

Example:
  SQL (without using Crystal) looks something like this:

```
SELECT D.REC ,D.CODE,
       (SELECT SUM(AMT)                               
          FROM TableT T2                                              
          WHERE T2.DELETED = 0                                         
            AND D.REC = T2.RID                            
            AND T2.TYPE = 65         
            AND T2.RES <> 10          
            AND LOT = 6) AS T2Total                                  
  FROM TableD D
  WHERE  D.DELETED=0
  GROUP BY D.CODE, REC
  ORDER BY D.CODE
```

There are more subselects and calculations in which I am no longer reading from 2 tables, but 4 and the records selected no longer have the same relationship and I was wondering if there was a way for me to write this in Crystal, I haven't found a way to create a stored proc for this

Any ideas/help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Best way in my opinion would be creating a VIEW for such scenarios. Add whatever you want to the view and then use the view in your report.